# Wordpress empty Nav Menu error

Tags: theme-development, multisite, menus, walker

i have created Multisite. i have assigned menu for the first sub domain while for the second sub domain i have not assigned Menu.

i just enabled the Debug mode and got Following error:

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home3/public_html/project/myproject/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 154**

i gone through couple of article and they suggested solution to use **Fallback**
**'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',** . i did try it but still shows Errors.

```
  $defaults = array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary',
       fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
       'menu_class'=> 'nav navbar-nav',
       'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                   );

      wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

is there any solution for it? how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

try and add your location as a parameter.

```
 <?php
if ( has_nav_menu( $location ) ) {
     //Do something
} ?>
```